# How to fetch the list of supported VM Sizes for an Azure region within an ARM template

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-rm-template

I would like my ARM template to dynamically show the list of VM sizes available in my Azure region so that I can choose a VM appropriately for my need. How should I enable this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with ARM Templates, but you can use other means to do that, for example Powershell:

```
Get-AzureRmVmSize -Location "East US"
```

And filter\sort the output and pass it as a parameter to the template you are invoking with `New-AzureRMResourceGroupDeployment`